# Flutter custom exception not throwing

Tags: flutter, dart, future

I upgraded Flutter from version 2.0.2 to version 2.2.2 and now the custom exceptions that are thrown from a Future function are not being catch.

For example, I got this Future function, where I call another Future that does a server request and returns back the response or throws a custom exception (ApiException) in case of error:

```
static Future<bool> signUpCustomerRequest(Map<String, dynamic> params) async {
    try {
      // Here we call this Future function that will do a request to server API.
      dynamic _response = await _provider.signUpCustomer(params);

      if (_response != null) {
        updateUserData(_response);

        return true;
      }

      return false;
    } on ApiException catch(ae) {
      // This custom exception is not being catch
      ae.printDetails();

      rethrow;
    } catch(e) {
      // This catch is working and the print below shows that e is Instance of 'ApiException'
      print("ERROR signUpCustomerRequest: $e");
      rethrow;
    } finally {

    }
  }
```

And this is the Future function that does the request to server and throws the ApiException:

```
Future<User?> signUpCustomer(Map<String, dynamic> params) async {
    // POST request to server
    var _response = await _requestPOST(
      needsAuth: false,
      path: routes["signup_client"],
      formData: params,
    );

    // Here we check the response...
    var _rc = _response["rc"];

    switch(_rc) {
      case 0:
        if (_response["data"] != null) {
          User user = User.fromJson(_response["data"]["user"]);

          return user;
        }

        return null;
      default:
        print("here default: $_rc");

        // And here we have the throw of the custom exception (ApiException)
        throw ApiException(getRCMessage(_rc), _rc);
    }
  }
```

Before upgrading to Flutter 2.2.2 the catch of custom exceptions worked perfectly. Did something change on this Flutter version? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your bug with the following code:

```
class ApiException implements Exception {
  void printDetails() {
    print("ApiException was caught");
  }
}

Future<void> doSomething() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  
  throw ApiException();
}

void main() async {
  try {
    await doSomething();
  } on ApiException catch (ae) {
    ae.printDetails();
  } catch (e) {
    print("Uncaught error: $e"); // This line is printed
  }
}
```

There's an open issue on the dart sdk, which I think might be related, though I'm not sure: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/45952.

In any case, I was able to correct the error by returning a `Future.error`, instead of throwing the error directly:

```
class ApiException implements Exception {
  void printDetails() {
    print("ApiException was caught"); // This line is printed
  }
}

Future<void> doSomething() async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
  
  return Future.error(ApiException());
}

void main() async {
  try {
    await doSomething();
  } on ApiException catch (ae) {
    ae.printDetails();
  } catch (e) {
    print("Uncaught error: $e");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank's for testing it!

I tried with the Future.error, but it does not work for me.

Comment: Ah, sorry to hear it - That was even with returning the Future.error, rather than throwing it?

Comment: Yes, did not work returning or throwing it.